# Allow a non-const to convert to const in a wrapper template

Tags: c++, templates

How can I allow a non-const reference to convert to a const reference in a wrapper template copy constructor? Note that my copy constructor is a logical move constructor (pre-C++11) -- the `init` member tracks which wrapper is currently valid.

```
template<typename T>
class wrap 
{
    T & object;
    bool init;
public:
    wrap( T& object ) : object(object), init( true ) { }

    //attempt which fails since "init" is private in other type
    template<typename O>
    wrap( wrap<O> const & o )
        : object( o.object )
        , init( true )
    {
        const_cast<wrap<O>&>(o).init = false;
    }
};
```

This works fine if the other type is exactly the same, since then access rules allow access to the private `init` variable. Basically, the following should work:

```
//adding const
wrap<Type> a( get() );
wrap<Type const> b = a;

//base type would also be nice
wrap<BaseType> c = a;
```

Comment: "This works fine if the other type is exactly the same" - actually, it doesn't. That will use the implicit copy constructor, not the template, so both will end up with `init` set.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Befriend other specialisations:

```
template <typename U> friend class wrap;
```

or for better encapsulation, just their conversion constructors:

```
template <typename U> template <typename O> 
friend wrap<U>::wrap(wrap<O> const &);
```

It would be better to declare `init` `mutable`; using `const_cast`, there's a risk of undefined behaviour if anyone tries to copy a `const` object.

Also, be aware that your constructor template *won't* overload the implicitly generated copy constructor. You'll also need a copy constructor to do the right thing with `init`:

```
wrap(wrap const & o) : object(o.object), init(true) {o.init = false;}
```

Comment: This works, but can you explain that crazy syntax for the second one? Why do I need two template parts?

Comment: @edA-qamort-ora-y: Because it's referring to a function template inside a class template; you need one `template` for each.

Answer (score 0):

Well to get around the access restrictions you could simply add other instantiations of `wrap` as a friend, so add `template<typename U> friend class wrap;` somewhere in the body of the class. That way your example should compile.

However you really shouldn't lie to the compiler like that. You pass `o` as `const ref`, promising not to change it and then change it anyways. This is not nice (or allowed by the standard), so the compiler can feel free to break your code in all manner of ways. You really should use `const_cast` for calling functions which take arguments as non const, but which will not change the arguments themselves (c apis come to mind). In this case I would suggest declaring the constructor as `template<typename O> wrap(wrap<O>& o)`. If you really want to take it as const reference you could also go the route of declaring `init` as `mutable`, which means it can be modified even if the object is `const`

You should also note that you are not declaring a copy constructor (even though `template<typename O> wrap( wrap<O> const & o )` can accept `wrap<T>`it does not count, so you need to define that too, or copying to the same type will use the compiler generated copy constructor.